# Generate random number in 2D array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am having trouble generating random numbers which randomly evaluate scores for each teacher assigned to a student with the fix  number of teachers per student n=5.The total numbers of teachers and students equal to 10.

this is my code:

```
       Random rand=new Random();

       for(i=1; i<10; i++ ){
           for(j=1; j<10; j++){
                e[i][j]= rand.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("e[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " +e[i][j]);
            } 
        }
```

but at my code i just gernerated random numbers that every teachers evaluated every students. i don't know how to fix the number of teachers per student n=5.
Could anyone pls help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This definitely does not belong on CodeGolf.SE, but rather on Stack Overflow. I'll migrate it. You should set up an account on Stack Overflow as well and associate it with this one in order to retain control as the author.

Comment: Hint: presumably one of your indicies represents the student and one the teacher. Obviously you don't want to want to take an action for all 10 teachers, which your simple for loop over that index is doing now. Instead you need to somehow select only five to use and then take action only for them.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any student or teacher object. It just shows an array of arrays. How are we supposed to understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assume 'i' is student id, 'j' is teacher id, there are 5 students and 5 teacher, so

> The total numbers of teachers and students equal to 10.

then:

```
  Random rand=new Random();

       for(i=0; i<5; i++ ){
           for(j=0; j<5; j++){
                e[i][j]= rand.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("e[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " +e[i][j]);
            } 
        }
```

I tried my best to understand your question, is this your wanted result?